# "Interpolation" oscillator working principle

Tags: rf, oscillator

I was reading Soviet amateur electronics magazines and stumbled upon an interesting oscillator.

It uses two high-frequency crystals (27.14 and 26.67 MHz) to to get a low-frequency output (465 kHz).

I'd like to know how it works and its possible drawbacks.

I presume, there's some kind of mixing action going on but I want to know for sure. The article only mentions that this circuit uses "interpolation method" but that doesn't tell me much. I think I've already seen something similar to this in English literature but I can't remember neither source nor the keywords for searching.

[image]